# How can I restrict CREATE TABLE access for a user (who has ddladmin membership) to a specific schema (sql server)?

Tags: sql-server-2012, privileges, sql-grant

i have one user who have ddladmin membership i want to restrict him on creating table on dbo schema can i do that ?
or i have to go for user define role

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REVOKE` for `CREATE TABLE` on the database to restrict that user from creating any tables.

Try the following sample:

```
REVOKE CREATE TABLE ON <DB_Name> FROM <UserName>
```

for Schema level, please try the following:

```
REVOKE CREATE TABLE ON SCHEMA::<schema_name> TO <UserName>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i want schema level restriction to user